# hibernate id generator AUTO_INCREMENT at h2 and MySQL in a cluster

Tags: java, hibernate, cluster-computing, auto-increment

For testing I'm using the **H2 database**.

For production it's **MySQL**.

I understrand that both support `AUTO_INCREMENT` ([mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) / [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#column_definition)), but it seems like Hibernate doesn't work this way.

`identity` is supported for MySQL. Fine.
What about H2? Should I write my own generator or...? (using the `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator` interface as the doc [says](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e2502)).

I must have a nice clean & quick way to get an ID (of type `long` by the way) from the database itself because **the application is in a cluster** (i.e several servers `INSERT` into the database at once)... that's why `increment` is definitely not for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: Using XML mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just annotate your id property which needs the generated value with @GeneratedValue. This will automatically select the appropriate generation strategy for the database you're using. See `GenerationType.AUTO` for more details.

Your property will look like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
```

Comment: hi and thanks. Sorry but: 1) I'm using XML mapping. 2) I specifically aim to MySQL and H2's feature of auto id generation, and not the alternatives that Hibernate offers such as HiLow etc'.

Comment: OK so use the XML alternative to the @Generated value. And the default generation strategy will use the database auto id generation.

Comment: Wish it was that simple - what is the alternative to `GenerationType.AUTO`? Can you see it ( http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e2502 )? I don't.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Hibernate will use the underlying database generation strategy if you tell it to.

Comment: that's exactly what I thought it'd do :)

Comment: that doesnt work for me... it passes the tests (h2) but it fails when you run the app (mariaDB 10.4)

Answer (score 2):

Use the native generator, for example

```
<id name="id" type="int">
    <column name="id_column" />
    <generator class="native" >
        <param name="sequence">id_column_sequence</param>
    </generator>            
</id>
```

The generator with the class `native` uses the best generation strategy for the database. In the case of MySql this is auto_increment, in the case of Oracle this is a sequence (and for H2  it also should be a sequence, but I've never tried, because I don't use H2). The generator parameter `sequence` only is used if it is useful, i. e. for MySql databases the parameter is ignored, and for Oracle it is used.

In that way you can use the same mapping file for different database types (at least as long as the table and column names are the same).

Comment: Why? Do you get a special error message? `native` also should work with H2.

Comment: @Johanna I have a similar problem.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252541/generatedvalue-polymorphic-abstract-superclass-over-mysql/25268134#25268134