# @GeneratedValue polymorphic abstract superclass over MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jpa

In a Spring MVC application using Hibernate and MySQL, I have an abstract superclass `BaseEntity` that manages the values of the IDs for all the other entities in the model.  The `id` field uses `@GeneratedValue`.  I am encountering a problem whenever my code tries to save any of the subclasses that extend `BaseEntity`.  The problem comes with the choice of `GenerationType` for the `@GeneratedValue`.

At every place in my code where a subclass of `BaseEntity` tries to save to the underlying MySQL database, I get the following error:

```
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Table 'docbd.hibernate_sequences' doesn't exist
```

I have read many postings about this on SO and on google, but they either deal with other databases (not MySQL) or they do not deal with abstract superclasses.  I cannot solve the problem by using `GenerationType.IDENTITY` because I am using an abstract superclass to manage `id` fields for all entities in the model.  Similarly, I cannot use `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` because MySQL does not support sequences.

So how do I solve this problem?

Here is the code for `BaseEntity.java`:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    protected Integer id;

    public void setId(Integer id) {this.id = id;}
    public Integer getId() {return id;}

    public boolean isNew() {return (this.id == null);}

}
```

Here is an example of the code for one of the entities that extends `BaseEntity`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ccd")
public class CCD extends BaseEntity{
    //other stuff
}
```

Here is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ccd(
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  #other stuff
)engine=InnoDB;SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Here is the JPQL code in the DAO:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveCCD(CCD ccd) {
    if (ccd.getId() == null) {
        System.out.println("[[[[[[[[[[[[ about to persist CCD ]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]");
        this.em.persist(ccd);
        this.em.flush();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]] about to merge CCD [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[");
        this.em.merge(ccd);
        this.em.flush();
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT:

The reason I cannot use `@MappedSuperClass` in this situation is that I need to have `ManyToOne` relationships that allow for multiple subtypes to be used interchangeably.  Look at the `AccessLog` class below as an example.  It has an `actor_entity` and a `target_entity`.  There can be many types of actor entities and many types of target entities, but they all inherit from `BaseEntity`.  This inheritance enables the underlying `accesslogs` data table in MySQL to just have one `actor_entity_id` field and just one `target_entity_id` field instead of having to have several fields for each.  When I change `@Entity` above `BaseEntity` to `@MappedSuperClass`, a different error gets thrown indicating that `AccessLog` cannot find `BaseEntity`.  `BaseEntity` needs `@Entity` annotation in order for `AccessLog` to have polymorphic properties.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accesslogs")
public class AccessLog extends BaseEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "actorentity_id")
    private BaseEntity actor_entity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "targetentity_id")
    private BaseEntity target_entity;

    @Column(name="action_code")
    private String action;
    //getters, setters, & other stuff
}
```

---

### SECOND EDIT:

As per JBNizet's suggestion, I created a hibernate_sequences table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hibernate_sequences(
  sequence_next_hi_value int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
)engine=InnoDB;SHOW WARNINGS;
```

But now I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'sequence_name' in 'where clause'
```

Here is the hibernate sql causing the error, followed by the next 2 lines of the stack trace:

```
Hibernate: select sequence_next_hi_value from hibernate_sequences where sequence_name = 'BaseEntity' for update
ERROR MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator - HHH000351: Could not read or init a hi value
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'sequence_name' in 'where clause'
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You should really not use entity inheritance to do that. The BaseEntity should be annotated with `@Mappedsuperclass`, not with `@Entity`.

Comment: Yes, you are looking for a mapped superclass. Rule of thumb: use inheritance when you need to perform queries on the base type, not knowing exactly what concrete instances will be returned.

Comment: why do you have a `BaseEntity` that manages the values of the IDs for all the other entities in the model?

Comment: @JBNizet I just added an edit to the end of my original posting above explaining why I cannot use `@MappedSuperClass` in this situation.  Does this help you see how to solve my problem?

Comment: @Henning I am using inheritance because I have classes like `AccessLog` which need to have polymorphic properties, all of which inherit from `BaseEntity`.  I added an edit to my original posting above to explain this.  Does this extra information help you see how my problem can be solved?

Comment: @Thufir `BaseEntity` enables its subclasses to be polymorphic.  I added an edit to my original posting to explain this.  Does this help you see the solution to the problem?

Comment: @JBNizet If I tried to use `@MappedSuperClass`, how would I accomplish the polymorphism required by my `AccessLog` class, which I included as an edit to my original posting above?

Comment: What's the problem with the table strategy? Hibernate tells you that it can't find the hibernate_sequences table. So, why not create it?

Comment: @JBNizet Please see my second edit at the end of my original posting above.  What else do I need to change to resolve this problem?

Comment: The error message is clear: the table needs to have a sequence_name column. Remember that the table strategy usually consists in using a single table to generate IDs for multiple, unrelated entities. So the name of the entity is used to get the next ID for this given entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use the TABLE identifier generator you need to have that table created. If you are not using the [enhanced identifier generators](http://vladmihalcea.com/from-jpa-to-hibernates-legacy-and-enhanced-identifier-generators/), chances are you are going to use the [MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/id/MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.html).

The MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator can use one table for all table identifier generators.

My suggestion is to grab the table ddl from your integration tests, in case you use hbmddl to build the test schema. If you use flyway or liquibase for testing, you can add a [maven plugin](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-integration-testing-strategies/) to generate the ddl schema.

Once you have the schema, you need to take the exact create table command and make add it to your MySQL database.

Comment: +1 and thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  I was able to resolve the error before I saw your response.  I just created a `hibernate_sequences` table with a `sequence_next_hi_value` field and a `sequence_name` field.  Hibernate seems to take care of the rest.  I wonder if behind the scenes it is doing the things you describe in your answer and blogs.

Comment: Yes it should. You should know that the TABLE generator uses locks (select for update) queries and an additional connection to commit the id generation in isolation of your current tx. So, while it's portable you might pay in performance cost.

Answer (score 4):

What a mess... `AUTO_INCREMENT` is MySQL's hidden sequence. The radical problem is that `MySQL` can not insert and return the PK at the same time, but Hibernate need this while `INSERT`ing a new Entity.

The Problems you run into:

1. If Hibernate save a new Entity, he try to immerdentelly set the id to the new EntityBean. Therefore hibernate must read what ID will the Database use before hibernate save the new Tuple to the Table.
2. If you have multiple Servers who access the database, you shall let hibernate's session-factory decide to use the built-in sequence(AUTO-INCREMENT) or let hibernate decide (`GenerationType.AUTO`/`GenerationType.IDENTITY`) how large the open range of reserved PK's is (Job of a DB-Architect). (We have about 20 servers to one Database, so on a good-used table we use a PK-distance of +100). If only one server have access to the database `GenerationType.TABLE` shall be correct.

Hibernate must calculate the next id by yourself using `max(*)+1` but:

- What if two requests ask for `max(*)+1` at the same time/with the same result? Right: The last try to `insert` will fail.

So you need to have a Table `LAST_IDS` in the database who stores the last Table-PK's. If you like to add one, you must do this steps:

1. Start read-optimistic transaction.
2. SELECT MAX(address_id) FROM LAST_IDS
3. store the maximum in a java-variable i.e.: $OldID.
4. $NewID = $OldID + 1.  (+100 in pessimistic-lock)
5. UPDATE LAST_IDS SET address_id= `$newID` WHERE address_id= `$oldID`?
6. commit the read-optimistic transaction.
7. if commit was successfull, store `$newID` to `setID()` in the HibernateBean you like to save.
8. Finally let Hibernate call the insert.

This is the only way i know.

BTW: Hibernate-Entitys shall only use inheritance if the Database support inheritance between tables like `PostgreSQL` or `Oracle`.

Comment: It depends on many questions like do you use transactions, what locking, how many servers do concurrent requests, what kind is the pk-fields, do you use innodb ...

Comment: +1 and thank you for taking the time to think about my question.  I resolved the error by simply creating the table and fields that were being specified in the error messages.